# Grouping strings in a list which have the same substing which is 4 letters in Python

Tags: python, string, list, grouping

This is an example list:

```
["aaaa", "cat" , "ccaatt" , "fish" , "ffish" , "dog", "doog" ,"bird" , "birdd" , "aaaab" , "aaaa".....]
```

Exptected output should be like this:

```
[("fish","ffish") , ("bird","birdd"), ("aaaa","aaaab","aaaa") ....]
```

or all possible double matchings:

```
[("fish","ffish"),("ffish","fish"),("bird","birdd"), ("birdd","bird"),("aaaa","aaaab"),("aaaa","aaaa"),("aaaab","aaaa") ....]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works well for small list (because of time complexity):

```
lst = ["aaaa", "cat", "ccaatt", "fish", "ffish", "dog", "doog", "bird",
       "birdd", "aaaab", "aaaa", 'fourrr', 'four']

lenght_four = {}
more_than_four = []

for item in lst:

    if len(item) > 4:
        more_than_four.append(item)

    elif len(item) == 4:
        exist = lenght_four.get(item)
        if exist is not None:
            exist.append(item)
        else:
            lenght_four[item] = []

for item in more_than_four:
    for k, v in lenght_four.items():
        if k in item:
            v.append(item)

res = [(k, *v) for k, v in lenght_four.items() if v]
print(res)
```

output :

```
[('aaaa', 'aaaa', 'aaaab'), ('fish', 'ffish'), ('bird', 'birdd'), ('four', 'fourrr')]
```

By iterating over the list we do these in one shot: (Thanks to @VPfB)

1- Excluding items that are less than 4.

2- Adding 4-lenght items in a dictionary.

3- Adding others which has `len(item) > 4` in a separate list.

Then we iterate over the items which has `len(item) > 4` to check if the items in 4-lenght list are sub-string of them or not.

Last we get the items in `lenght_four` dictionary which their value is not empty list.

Comment: IMO two passes are needed. One to extract 4-letter words and one to find similar words. Try with reversed order: `"ffish", "fish"`.

Comment: @VPfB oops, you're right, I changed the code a bit. That should be fix by now I think.

Comment: Thank you very much but If there are  same strings in the list this code doesn't work I will edit my question.

Comment: @tako0707 I've updated my answer as well. check it out. btw in you question `aaaaa` is not acceptable as you stated before, it should be `aaaa` (4 letters)

Comment: Thank you so much and It's working now. I edited my question again

Comment: @tako0707 happy to help

Answer (score 0):

You can combine `filter` and **comprehension** together to get the required result.

```py
>>> data = ["cat" , "ccaatt" , "fish" , "ffish" , "dog", "doog" ,"bird" , "birdd"]
>>> list(filter(lambda i: len(i)>=2,[tuple(x
                                       for x in data if item in x)
                                 for item in filter(lambda i: len(i) == 4, data)]))

#output: [('fish', 'ffish'), ('bird', 'birdd')]
```

Answer (score 0):

if there is only similar word:

```
>>>  wlist = ["cat" , "ccaatt", "ccccattt" , "fish" , "ffish", "ffffishhh" , "dddog", "dog", "doog" ,"bird" , "birdd"]
>>> d = {}
>>> for w in wlist:
...  if len(k) == 4:
...   d[''.join(dict.fromkeys(w).keys())] = w
... 
>>> d
{'fish': 'ffish', 'bird': 'birdd'}
```

otherwise with more accourrences:

```
>>> wlist =  wlist = ["cat" , "ccaatt", "ccccattt" , "fish" , "ffish", "ffffishhh" , "dddog", "dog", "doog" ,"bird" , "birdd"]
>>> d = {}
>>> for w in wlist:
...  k = ''.join(dict.fromkeys(w).keys())
...  if k != w and len(k) == 4:
...   if k in d:
...    d[k].append(w)
...   else:
...    d[k] = [w]
... 
>>> d
{'fish': ['ffish', 'ffffishhh'], 'bird': ['birdd']}
>>>
```

in both, you can convert the result from dict to a list of tuple with

```
[(k, v) for k, v in d.items() if v]
```

For example:

```
>>> [(k, v) for k, v in d.items() if v]
[('fish', ['ffish', 'ffffishhh']), ('bird', ['birdd'])]
```

Answer (score 0):

If the pattern remains the same, you can make use of `zip` and list comprehension.

```py
print([(x, y) for x, y in zip(lst[0::2], lst[1::2]) if x in y and len(x)==4])
```

another way

```py
lst = ["cat" , "ccaatt" , "fish" , "ffish" , "dog", "doog" ,"bird" , "birdd"]

print([(lst[x], lst[x+1]) for x in range(0, len(lst), 2) if len(lst[x]) == 4 and lst[x] in lst[x+1]])
```

output:

```
[('fish', 'ffish'), ('bird', 'birdd')]
```